# How to open electron with a different session

Tags: electron, nightmare

I would like to open several Electron browser windows with a new session every time.

Like if I have Chrome open a URL and sign in a user. Then I can open Chrome in private mode and have it ask me the login details again. I just need more than just 2 windows.

Is it possible with NightmareJs? Is it even possible outside of NightmareJs and without VMs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting a different `userData` path for every session.

```
return Nightmare({
        paths: {
            userData: `my/path/${account}`
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use what was built in and intended for this: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#user-content-cookies

```
.cookies.clearAll()
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Thx Shane for the answer. I can't verify it at the moment. If anybody comments on your answer that it's working I'll accept the vote.